# "File is in owner's trash"

Tags: discussion, questions

On the last days I found some [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) questions that have a link to demo spreadsheets that were moved to the owners' trash.

The textual message shown when opening any of these spreadsheets is:

> File is in owner's trash
>
> You won't be able to access this file soon.
>   If you still need access, please download it or copy and paste its contents.

[image]

In the specific case of [Filter & Sort with merged cells / groups of rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/111458/88163) this question has around 8 months old, has 0 score, has an answer that look more as comment than an answer with a score of -1.

The question doesn't include a screenshot of the demo spreadsheet or other mean to show the spreadsheet structure and content.

What should we do on these cases?

Answer (score 4):

If the question relies on links that no longer work, then it should probably be closed with "unclear what you are asking". I would say that on balance such questions probably aren't worth saving.

A down-vote might get the OP's attention, but even then it might not be enough for them to fix up the question so it doesn't rely on soon to be dead links.

Comment: Since the question and its answer haven't positive score I proceeded as it's suggested. Lets see if the OP comeback and do something on their post.